# Change UIToolbar Font Size - iOS

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, font-size

Is there a way to change the size of the font in a UIToolbar?  My text does not fit so I need to make it smaller.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered rewriting the text? The font is that size for a reason.

Comment: I have.  But I would rather try to make it smaller. Only by a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example. I am not sure what you want, but you can resize the font size of uibarbuttonitem in uitoolbar.

```
 UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,10,15)];
             label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
             label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
             label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
             //label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
             label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
             label.text = @"Bar";


     UIBarButtonItem *item2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   
     initWithCustomView:label];
```